# Codeigniter: Get Date From DateTime Mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Query Codeigniter:

```
$bookvisit = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                            (
                                SELECT 
                                    name 
                                FROM 
                                    tbl_user as u 
                                WHERE 
                                    u.user_id=b.user_id
                            ) as BookVisitFrom,
                                 b.status as status,
                                 b.booktime as booktime,
                                 b.bookdate as bookdate,
                                --> b.created as created,
                                 b.is_confrim as is_confrim,
                                 b.id as id
                            FROM 
                                tbl_bookvisit as b
                           ");
```

I want only Date from DateTime from the "created"(its column name) how can i get it!!

Comment: So what are you getting right now and in which format

Comment: This query working?It should produce error.`WHERE                               u.user_id=b.user_id` is invalid statement

Comment: yes this query is working

Comment: i am getting all database values but in need DATE only in created column

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date` function for it

```
date(b.created)  as created

mysql> select date('2015-01-01 20:30:40') as only_date ;
+------------+
| only_date  |
+------------+
| 2015-01-01 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```